# C, OpenSSL and AES 256 CTR, then mkfs

Tags: c, linux, encryption, openssl, aes

I am encrypting XFS filesystem using OpenSSL 1.0.2 (cannot update) and AES-256 in ctr mode (using sector number as a IV). I am encrypting only blocks of 512B at one time.

At first I started with `EVP_aes_256_ecb()` **ECB mode for testing and en/decrypt is working fine**.

With same code I am also going for CTR (`EVP_aes_256_ctr()`):

```
encrypt(...) {

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len;
    int ciphertext_len;
    if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();
    if (EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, evp_cipher, NULL, key, iv) != 1)
        handleErrors();
    if (EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0) != 1)
        handleErrors();
    if (EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len) != 1)
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len = len;
    if (EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len) != 1)
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len += len;
    if (tag && EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, 16, tag) != 1)
        handleErrors();
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    return ciphertext_len;
}

int decrypt(...) {
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len;
    int plaintext_len;
    if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();
    if (EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, evp_cipher, NULL, key, iv) != 1)
        handleErrors();
    if (EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0) != 1)
        handleErrors();
    if (EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len) != 1)
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len = len;
    if (tag && !EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG, 16, tag))
        handleErrors();
    if (EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len) != 1) {
        if (tag) {
            printf("Tag verify failed.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        handleErrors();
    }
    plaintext_len += len;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    return plaintext_len;
}
```

Only in this case after `mkfs.xfs` I am getting:

```
specified blocksize 4096 is less than device physical sector size 4194304
switching to logical sector size 512
meta-data=/dev/sdb               isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=2097152 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=0, sparse=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=8388608, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=4096, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
bad magic number
bad magic number
Metadata corruption detected at xfs_sb block 0x0/0x200
libxfs_writebufr: write verifer failed on xfs_sb bno 0x0/0x200
releasing dirty buffer (bulk) to free list!
```

This isn't very nice. Is there any problem with my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I haven't found a reason, I inspired my code by this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saju/misc/master/misc/openssl_aes.c and it is working now. Code in this link seems to be compatible with OpenSSL 1.0.2.